# Trying to return a value from switch case to a switch case but doesn't work

Tags: c

Firstly, I'd just like to clarify that this is my first time on this site and, i'm very new to coding in general. This is my first language :') My code is probably extremely messy and could be done a lot better, so please go easy on me...!

i've got a switch case within an int function.

**The problem is:**

I'm trying to make it so that whatever seat is taken is memorized, and the seat can not be taken again. I have tried returning 'result' from the function to go through the switch case but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be returning correctly as I keep getting the default of that statement, which returns an error message to me.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: In your `main()`, when you call `standardType()`, you did not use a variable (e.g. `result`) to store the return value.

Comment: You can either pass `result` by reference `standardType()` function or store its return value in `result` variable.

Comment: Please, where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two possibilities to recover the result,

1) The first approach you have to get the result of the function like this:

```
result = standardType(type, snumber, result, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
```

With this approach you did not need to pass in parameter the result, you can directly return "return 1 or other value"

2) The second approach (pass the address of the result variable as a parameter of the function)

```
void standardType(char type, int snumber, int* result, int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
...
*result = 1;
...
}

// in main
 int main()
{
    char choice, type;
    int snumber, cont=1, result;
    int s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;

while (cont != 0)
{

    printf("\n\nWelcome to Cinema System.\n        Choose ‘S’ for Standard Type, ‘G’ for Gold Type and 'X' to exit:\n\n");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    switch(choice){

case 'S':
     standardType(type, snumber, &result, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);

...
}
```

In this example, you directly modify the value of the result variable via the address of the variable.

The variable symbol &var gives the address of the variable in memory and the variable symbol *var gives access to the value via the address.